# What does "l'autre semaine" mean?

Tags: sens

> C'est le petit garçon dont je vous parlais **l'autre semaine.** On me
>   l'a confié pour un mois; son père et sa mère voyagent en Espagne.

This is from ["PATACHOU" by Tristan Derème](http://tristan-dereme.fr/tag/patachou/).

I am glad if someone kindly teach me what "l'autre semaine" means.

Does it mean as below?

This is the boy whom I told you in another week.

Comment: "L'autre semaine" is exactly the same as the English "the other week"  (**not** another week) it refers in both languages to a preceding week; despite of the use of the definite article in both languages, the date is not precise.  In most contexts "Another week" (French *une autre semaine* ) would mean "a different week", it is not what is meant here. And in English it would be ".. whom I told you **about** the other week".

Answer (score 4):

The expression “*l'autre jour*” means “some day in the recent past”. Despite the definite article, it does not always refer to a specific day. It's an idiom. When the day hasn't been mentioned before, it's more or less interchangeable with “*il y a quelques jours*” (“a few days ago”). However “*l'autre jour*” also works when some additional qualification is given. English has a similar idiom: “the other day”.

> J'ai croisé Marie l'autre jour.   *I bumped into Marie the other day.*
> J'ai croisé Marie il y a quelques jours.   *I bumped into Marie a few days ago.*
>
> Quand je suis passé à Paris l'autre jour, il faisait beau.   *When I was in Paris the other day, the weather was nice.*

This construction can also be used with longer time periods, but it's a lot rarer. So “*l'autre semaine*” (rare) means a few weeks ago, “*l'autre mois*” (very rare) means a few months ago, etc. [This diagram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27autre+jour+%2F+le+jour%2C+l%27autre+semaine+%2F+la+semaine%2C+l%27autre+mois+%2F+le+mois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28l%27%20autre%20jour%20/%20le%20jour%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28l%27%20autre%20semaine%20/%20la%20semaine%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28l%27%20autre%20mois%20/%20le%20mois%29%3B%2Cc0) compares the approximate relative frequency of “*l'autre jour*” among the uses of “*jour*”, with the same relative frequency for *semaine* and *mois*.

This construction can also be used with recurring events: “*l'autre fois*” = “the other time” = a few occurrences of some event ago. Sometimes “*l'autre fois*” refers to the last occurrence before the present (i.e. it's a synonym of “*la dernière fois*”), sometimes to an earlier (but not much earlier) occurrence. Similarly, “*l'autre soir*” means a few days ago in the evening, “*l'autre matin*” means a few days ago in the morning, etc.

If you use the indefinite article, then the meaning changes to some future occurrence that is not yet determined.

> Nous en parlerons une autre fois.   *We'll talk about this some other time.*
> Je reviendrai un autre jour.   *I'll come back some other day.*

Thus, in the sentence from *Patachou*, it is implied that the two people having the conversation talked a few weeks ago. During this earlier conversation, the speaker told the other person about a little boy.

Comment: Gilles,thank you so much for your kind and detailed answer! The usage of this idiom is so clear to me now/

Answer (score 1):

*L'autre semaine* refers here to the week before the current one, or, depending of the context, the last week these people talked together.

*L'autre* is versus the current one.